# Cannot get GPS in background of iOS (background mode plugin enabled)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, gps, background-process

Hi guys can you save me from the project's cliff.

**Background:**

I have a Ionic project based on Map template. What it does is tracking the walking route of user and draw it to google map.

Problem appears on *iOS devices* with background running. I cannot get the GPS data correctly. 
FYI: BackgroundMode plugin installed and set up.

> **Scenario 1: Use cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin**
>
> It does not work. No GPS data collected when turning off screen.

> **Scenario 2: Use plain JS with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition**
>
> It works. GPS data collected but *not correct*. Data is somehow duplicated (!!) from previous ones. Thing get back to normal when I open 
>   the app again.

Any idea would help.

---

**Plugins used:**
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.6.5
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.1.5
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.0
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.1
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.2
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.0.1

---

**Edited:**
*Target platform?*
iOS 7+, and Android 4.1+ as required from Ionic.

*Test device iOS version?*
iOS 9.2 (13C75) on iPhone 5

*Have you tested your App in the foreground?*
Yes I do. To clarify, here is more detailed test:

I have two test functions: One array for gps collecting and one counter for background mode checking. Both are running under interval set.

(on iOS)
Foreground:
Counter works, number is increased.
GPS works, data is added to array.

Background:
Counter works, number is increased.
GPS not works, data is either not collected (with ngCordova geolocation plugin) or is oddly duplicated with JS navigator.geolocation

Comment: What is your target platform and their target versions: iOS 7,8,9? What version of iOS is your test device? Have you tested your App in the foreground? Please **answer the questions in your post**. Once you have answer the question, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: hi @JesseMonroy650, thank for your help. More detailed are added

Comment: Can you please add with version is on your iOS test device? There are serious bugs with 9.2 and 9.3. Apple released 9.3.1 just days ago.

Comment: It's 9.2 (13C75) on iPhone 5

Comment: My comments are also a hint. Google [ios 9.2 bug](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+9.2+bug) -- [iOS 9.2 Problems: 5 Things You Need to Know](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2016/01/18/ios-9-2-problems/) - See: "Still Plaguing Users"

Comment: lastly, since I dont use 9.x on any devices I can't say. However on Android (which you are not using), background service is severly limited on Android 6.X Best of Luck

Comment: @JesseMonroy650: Thank you so much on your participant and guideline. I am checking more on this. I will feedback the solution if it works. How can I give my reputation for you? Can't find it work in comments.

Comment: thank you for the offer of reputation. I would to know that you are doing well with your app. My goal is always to help developers do better. I am always happy to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled background location mode for your ios app? before doing the build, check your .plist file do ensure your app has "background modes" enabled and "location services" are checked/listed under "background modes".

[image]

Also ensure that your .plist file contains `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, without which the device will not ask for `Always` usage permission for location and location will only be available based on `NSLocationWhenInUseDescription`.

**Update:**
You will need one more step to ensure app correctly asks 'always' running in background permission.

*How:*
 - Search in your xcode project for **CDVLocation.m** file, then find code block contain `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
 - Reorder if else conditions, move `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` condition to first line

[image: Make sure app asking for always background running permission]

*(optional)*
If youre doing your builds via ionic cli, run `ionic prepare ios`, then open your project in xcode and confirm the above settings, as they usually get overwritten by cordova plugins, unless you've specifically set up scripts for `after_install` and other events.

Comment: hi @mani. Thanks. I tried but it did not work. Background mode ran but gps data was duplicated as I reported in question.

Comment: I am checking on more  iOS versions as noticed by @JesseMonroy650

Comment: after doing the build, on the device/emulator, could you go to settings -> your_app_name -> Location, and confirm that the permission `allow location access` is set to `always` - just to confirm that your .plist contains `NSlocationalwaysusagedescription` and the correct location permissions are being requested + granted.

Comment: hi @mani. That EXACTLY where I should look into. I have the app run correctly. *Bravo*. However, it's NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription (camel case); and the problem need extra works than just .plist only. It's was the generated code from Ionic which does asking only GPS permission for foreground running by default. I will write the solution on my question. Thanks again for the clue.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll update the answer for future reference.

Comment: Can you publish your solution @Quy?

Comment: Hi @Eusthace, I have finalised solution by editing mani's answer to add one more missing step. He has almost got there, just need to make sure app ask for **'Always'** permission when requesting user for background run (always = run even when app is minimized). Not sure if you can see the changes now or need to wait for some peer reviews per StackOverflow's policy.